# How can I fix the AWS EMR Spark toPandas() error?

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

When trying to run the following code on AWS EMR with Spark:

```
pre_stage_1 = spark.read.csv("s3://e/s.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true") 
knn_imputed = pre_stage_1.toPandas().copy(deep=True)
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.PooledRemoteClient.callRemoteFunction(PooledRemoteClient.java:100)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:98)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:221)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:490)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:72)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.lambda$new$0(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:60)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteClientFactory.create(RemoteClientFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteClientFactory.create(RemoteClientFactory.java:34)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.PooledRemoteClient.getClient(PooledRemoteClient.java:54)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.PooledRemoteClient.callRemoteFunction(PooledRemoteClient.java:92)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.lambda$new$0(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:58)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
    ... 22 more
```

pre_stage_1 is a dataset with about 1000000 rows, and I have changed the spark.executor.memory to
6G.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your error being `Connection refused`, I am thinking that it is most likely a network or authentication problem.

So, check:

- Network, how do you connect to your different services?
- Authentication, what are your credentials?